# I couldn't find stress tester in OrientDB 3.x

Tags: orientdb

I have been going through the documentation of OrientDB about Stress tester. But I couldn't find the script for it in my setup's bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

the script for the stress test was present in version older than 3.x

Comment: We have jar for stress tester in 3.x /lib. May be I have to try writing compatible script.

Answer (score 0):

You can take `stresstester.sh` from, for example, OrientDB 2.2 and adapt it for your version.

Here is `/orientdb/bin/stresstester.sh` from 2.2.37:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set ORIENTDB_HOME if not already set
[ -f "$ORIENTDB_HOME"/lib/orientdb-tools-2.2.37.jar ] || ORIENTDB_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." ; pwd`
export ORIENTDB_HOME


# Set JavaHome if it exists
if [ -f "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" ]; then
   JAVA=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
else
   JAVA=java
fi
export JAVA

exec "$JAVA" -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512g -cp "$ORIENTDB_HOME/lib/*" \
    com.orientechnologies.orient.stresstest.OStressTester $*
```

In my case I only had to change `orientdb-tools-2.2.37.jar` to `orientdb-tools-3.0.33.jar` in order to run this script with OrientDB 3.0.33 I have installed.